# Why is the definite article used in each of these places in this sentence?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I found this sentence on the British Council website. I don't know why "the" is used in the sentence because all of the nouns seem indefinite:

> Imagine a beach; a quiet place, with only **the** noise of **the** sea and **the** gulls in **the** background.

Comment: 'In the background' is a set phrase. It carries a hint of definiteness, as do 'in the air' and 'in the meantime', suggested by the context (the beach in your imagination; the bit of sky surrounding you; the time interval between the fixed points). Similarly 'the sea' (by your notional beach). 'The gulls' carries a fainter hint (and assumes that your imagination, and that the beaches you're familiar with, are fairly predictable). 'The noise of the sea' is specifying _which_ noise and so uses 'the' before 'noise'. Compare 'the sound of music'; 'the rise and fall of Reginald Perrin'.

Comment: This seems dated; I'd say the semicolon usage is non-standard nowadays.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *The sound of music*, *The rise and fall of Reginald Perrin* You're practically giving away your security and national health insurance number there :) P.S Why don't you post your comment as an answer, it's very good.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou My great great grandparents used to.... / I'm pretty sure these will have been covered here before – and that it would take weeks to track down duplicates. Also, that the 'the gulls' example would be hard to provide corroboration for.

Comment: You could say "gulls" in place of "the gulls".  But I wold not omit the other instances of "the".

Comment: Why do you say "the definite article used" rather than "a definite article used"?

Answer (score 5):

Once you restrict the sentence to the beach that you're imagining, all the related objects become definite -- you're referring specifically to the objects related to that beach. So it becomes "*the* sea" because you're only talking about the one sea connected to that beach, and "*the* noise" because it's just the noise of that one sea.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you say *Imagine a **beach*** you can refer to things usually found or associated with a (any) beach using the definite article.

The same for anything: it was *an old house* and the front door creaked and the walls needed painting and the roof had holes in it and the owner was nowhere to be found.